# ios app rejected because not authorizated to use MFi hardware

Tags: ios, hardware, ipod, verification, mfi

**This statement is from Apple about my app**:

> We are unable to post your app to the App Store at this time because
>   we have no verification that you are authorized to distribute apps
>   that interact with the required MFi hardware.
>
> Please work with the required hardware vendor to contact the
>   appropriate MFi account specialist to provide the necessary
>   verification.
>
> While your iTunes Connect Application State is displayed as Rejected,
>   it is not necessary to upload a new binary. Once you have provided the
>   necessary verification to the hardware vendor's MFi account
>   specialist, please respond to this message and we will proceed with
>   your review.
>
> If you haven't yet provided your MFi Certification PPID# in the Review
>   Notes, please add this number to the Review Notes for your app in
>   iTunes Connect.

I wrote an email to vendor, but he didn't answer me. I don't know what to do? Any help would be appreciated.

---

My app print fiscal ticket with a serial cable made for ipod of Redpark factory and i use their sdk.

I talk with the Redpark and he siaid me that that cable is made for apple bat not for apple store,if i want for $2000/3000 abd 4/5 month.
I think that are crazy,infact if i'm autoryzed i don't reload the binary

Comment: What does your application do and does it connect to any hardware (Bluetooth or otherwise?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Redpark SDK you are using is targeted more for enterprise use, where they could deploy applications without going through the app store.

If you really want an app that prints in the app store, why not simply using the existing print API's to print to wireless printers?

If the app is targeting a specific kind of receipt printer the price they are asking for certification is very reasonable, and you simply have to pay it.

Answer (score 1):

From the Redpark web page: [Redpark - Serial Cable - C2 - DB9](http://www.redpark.com/c2db9.html)

> The cable is used in conjunction with the Redpark Serial Cable SDK.
>   Together these tools enable hobbyist, education and enterprise
>   developers to write iOS apps that communicate with serial devices.
>   These apps may be deployed for private use at home, at school or in an
>   office. **Under current Apple policy this cable may not be used with
>   apps sold on the App Store.**

So Redpark knows you can't currently do what you want to do.  But it seems that for a price they might be able to do a work around.

The only alternatives are to not distribute your app through the app store - either as an app for a jail broken system, or as an enterprise app for a specific customer.

Comment: i have read what you write before bay a cable but for me school,educatation,office not need,it need only a developer to use this cable,so the made for ipod like it don't need nobody.